# Cassandra one CqlSession shared in 40 threads sometime CQL return empty no record

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra

Environment:

- OS: CentOS7
- JDK 11.0.7
- Cassandra cluster: 17 nodes (built by other person)
- Cassandra driver: com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.12.0

The Cassandra cluster was not built by me, but by other cassandra experts. I just designed a java client to read it (no write). I only know that there are 17 nodes, and replica is config to 3.

My program has 40~50 threads sharing with one CqlSession. The code is sort of complicated that I can not show all of them. So I just show the relevant portion.

Init CqlSession (I only use 4 contact points):

```
    cqlSession = CqlSession.builder()
            .withAuthCredentials("mudr_read", "OOXXOOXX!")
            .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(contactPoint, port))
            .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.121", port))
            .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.122", port))
            .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.123", port))
            .withLocalDatacenter("dc1")
            .withKeyspace("keyspace").build();
```

I was given a CQL like below:

```
select channel_id, interval_end_time,  flags,lp_value, validation_status, version_start_time
from mudr.lp_intervals_2021
where channel_id in (
                      4040239,4040245,4040852,15008307,15008311,15008312,15004568,15004571,15004575
                      ,9534062,9534066,9534067,9519301,9520004,9520006,15034324,15034325,15034327,3983465,
                     3983470,3983475,25789081,25789084,25789088,25818675,25818677,25818681,22401049,22401602,22401603
    )
and interval_end_time > '2021-05-01 00:00:00+0800' and interval_end_time <='2021-05-02 00:00:00+0800';
```

The fetch code is:

```
List<Data> results = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet rs = cqlSession.execute(cql);
for(Row: row) {
  results.add(new Data(
        row.getString("field1");
        row.getString("field2");
         .....
  ));
}
```

The data is very huge and those data will not be deleted. There are about 250 millions channel_ids distributed among 40~50 threads for querying data from Cassandra with the above CQL. And the `interval_end_time` is from 2021-05-01 to present.

And I realize that occationally the above CQL run in CqlSession.execute() returns no data.  The Probability of occurrence is about 10%. Whenever this situation happenes, with the same CQL running in other database tool such as DataGrip, it can return correct quantity of data.

I have been tried two days. No any improvement.

Did I miss some configuraition?

Comment: Can you edit your post with the table definition?  Specifically, the primary key(s)?  That's not a very efficient CQL query.  If it's querying on indexed, non-key columns it could be timing out...especially if the partitions are large.

Comment: @Aaron Eventually I found the error is caused by one method created by me. The method was to format Date to string and it was not thread-safe. So sometime it caused the last criteria date string in CQL wrong.  But I manually corrected it when I tested the CQL in database tool. So this cause is not related to Cassandra.
Anyway, I decide to close(or delete) this question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `channel_id` is the partition key for the table, your query might go fine with 2 or 3 keys in the `IN()` operator. In my experience, anything more than that does not scale and will not perform well because it puts the coordinator node under pressure.

For each `IN()` item, the coordinator has to fire off separate requests to get the result. In the example you provided where there are 29 items, your single CQL query is broken up into 29 different queries.

This might be ok for a single-node or 3-node cluster but in your case, the coordinator has to fire 29 different requests to 17 nodes in your cluster.
On top of that, you are performing a range scan. If there are indexed columns involved, the coordinator has to query the indexes on each of the nodes in the cluster to get the results. As Aaron pointed out, the query is likely timing out because it is expensive. Cheers!